# Don't rotate the web in landscape view

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sass, landscape

When I rotate the phone to landscape view, I still want to see the web page in portrait view. It is possible to force this only with CSS?

Comment: Stone you should mark correct or vote up to the answers on your question..

Comment: I would be glad if you could even vote my answer your..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its also easy to re-rotate using css..

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) { 
body {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
}}
```

But as mentioned in the other answer... it is a better to make a more userfriendly layout for landscape view as well...

Answer (score 3):

This could lower the UX tremendously, seeing as the viewport is now only half the height. In most cases it makes more sense to simply make the landscape-view more userfriendly (though it's rarely gonna be as nice as portrait!).

---

To answer your question, though:

Using media queries you could use the `orientation` media property and make your container width equal to the viewport height.

Something like the following:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #container-div {
        width: 100vh;
    }
}
```